# What must be the output dim for word embedding in keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, word-embedding

What must be the dimension of the dense embedding? How can we set the value of output_dim in keras for word_embedding?

```
 keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, embeddings_initializer='uniform', embeddings_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, embeddings_constraint=None, mask_zero=False, input_length=None)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Embeding layer convert categorical variable(words) to vector. Output dimension specify how long this vector will be.

If you chose 10, than every word will be converted to vector with size 10. Value of this vector will be optimized during training. If you need figure out which output dimension is best for your problem, I recommend to find similar project and try use their output dimension size. Other option is try some sizes and judge which one suits best.